# Joining Two Pieces of jSON Data

Tags: php, json

I am trying to retrieve data from https://bushell.net/betfair.php and then implement the correct prices for the 'section_id' which are unique horses. I use the market id key, which is unique, and access another URL,

e.g. https://uk-api.betfair.com/www/sports/exchange/readonly/v1.0/bymarket?currencyCode=GBP&alt=json&locale=en_GB&types=MARKET_STATE%2CRUNNER_STATE%2CRUNNER_EXCHANGE_PRICES_BEST&marketIds=1.147791452

(the market_id is a varible, and you can get that from https://bushell.net/betfair.php)

[image]

and then spit it out using an echo.

Somewhere my code isn't working, logically, it seems as though it should though?

```
<?php

echo date("Y-m-d h:i:s");

echo "<br>";



ini_set('max_execution_time', 30000);



$curl = curl_init();



curl_setopt_array($curl, array(

    CURLOPT_URL => "https://bushell.net/betfair.php",

    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,

    CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",

    CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,

    CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 3000000,

    CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false

    ));



$response = curl_exec($curl);

$err = curl_error($curl);



curl_close($curl);



if ($err) 

{

    echo "cURL Error #:" . $err;

} 

else

{

    $master_data = array();

    $price_data = array();

    $size_data = array();



    $marketIds = "";



    $response = json_decode($response,true);

    foreach ($response as $key => $value) 

    {

        $name = "";

        $d = null;

        $d1 = null;



        $marketIds .= $value['marketId'].",";



        foreach ($value['runners'] as $keyInner => $valueInner) 

        {

            $d = explode("T", $value['marketStartTime']);

            $d1 = explode(".", $d[1]);

            $curl1 = curl_init();



            $name = $value['event']['venue'];



            $temp = array();

            $temp['image'] = "<img src='https://content-cache.cdnbf.net/feeds_images/Horses/SilkColours/".$valueInner['metadata']['COLOURS_FILENAME']."'>";

            $temp['runnerName'] = $valueInner['runnerName'];

            $temp['jockey'] = $valueInner['metadata']['JOCKEY_NAME'];

            $temp['venue'] = $value['event']['venue']."-".$value['marketName'];

            $temp['dateTime'] = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($value['marketStartTime']));

            $temp['odds'] = 0.0;

            $temp['selectionId'] = $valueInner['selectionId'];

            $master_data[] = $temp;

        }


          //New api end - market id comma

    $curl2 = curl_init();
    curl_setopt_array($curl2, array(
      CURLOPT_URL => "https://uk-api.betfair.com/www/sports/exchange/readonly/v1.0/bymarket?currencyCode=GBP&alt=json&locale=en_GB&types=MARKET_STATE%2CRUNNER_STATE%2CRUNNER_EXCHANGE_PRICES_BEST&marketIds=".$marketIds,
      CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
      CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
      CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
      CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30000,
      CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
      CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "GET",
      CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false
    ));


    $response2 = curl_exec($curl2);
    $err2 = curl_error($curl2);
    curl_close($curl2);

    if ($err2) 

    {

      echo "cURL Error #:" . $err2;

    }

    else 

    {

        $odds_array = json_decode($response2,true);

        foreach ($odds_array['eventTypes'][0]['eventNodes'] as $key2 => $value2) 

        {

            foreach ($value2['marketNodes'][0]['runners'] as $key_runner => $value_runner) 

            {

                $price_data[$value_runner['selectionId']] = @$value_runner['exchange']['availableToBack'][0]['price'];

                $size_data[$value_runner['selectionId']] = @$value_runner['exchange']['availableToBack'][0]['size'];  

            };

        }

        //die;

    }




    foreach ($master_data as $key => $value) 

    {
            $back_odds = @$price_data[$value['selectionId']];

            echo $value['image'];
            echo $value['runnerName']."<br>";
            echo "<strong>Jockey: </strong>". $value['jockey']."<br>";
            echo "<strong>Venue: </strong>".$value['venue']."<br>";
            echo "<strong>Date/Time: </strong>".$value['dateTime']."<br>";
            echo "<strong>Betfair Back Odds: </strong>".$back_odds."<br>";
            echo "<hr>";
    }

}

echo "<br>";

        ?>
```

Comment: You should explain what you are getting that is not what you were expecting. Also, if your code just flat out errors, then provide that as well. Turn on all error debug, or you may go in circles.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

can you show me some error when you run your PHP code?

So, I ran your PHP code and I see an error, I fix it by adding a "}" that was not closing the "if" statement.

```
<?php
 echo date("Y-m-d h:i:s");
 echo "<br>";
 ini_set('max_execution_time', 30000);
 $curl = curl_init();
 curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
CURLOPT_URL => "https://bushell.net/betfair.php",
CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 3000000,
CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false
));
$response = curl_exec($curl);
$err = curl_error($curl);
curl_close($curl);

if ($err){
   echo "cURL Error #:" . $err;
}else
{
$master_data = array();
$price_data = array();
$size_data = array();
$marketIds = "";
$response = json_decode($response,true);

foreach ($response as $key => $value){
    $name = "";
    $d = null;
    $d1 = null;
    $marketIds .= $value['marketId'].",";
    foreach ($value['runners'] as $keyInner => $valueInner){
        $d = explode("T", $value['marketStartTime']);
        $d1 = explode(".", $d[1]);
        $curl1 = curl_init();
        $name = $value['event']['venue'];
        $temp = array();
        $temp['image'] = "<img src='https://content-cache.cdnbf.net/feeds_images/Horses/SilkColours/".$valueInner['metadata']['COLOURS_FILENAME']."'>";
        $temp['runnerName'] = $valueInner['runnerName'];
        $temp['jockey'] = $valueInner['metadata']['JOCKEY_NAME'];
        $temp['venue'] = $value['event']['venue']."-".$value['marketName'];
        $temp['dateTime'] = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($value['marketStartTime']));
        $temp['odds'] = 0.0;
        $temp['selectionId'] = $valueInner['selectionId'];
        $master_data[] = $temp;
    }


    //New api end - market id comma
    $curl2 = curl_init();
    curl_setopt_array($curl2, array(
        CURLOPT_URL => "https://uk-api.betfair.com/www/sports/exchange/readonly/v1.0/bymarket?currencyCode=GBP&alt=json&locale=en_GB&types=MARKET_STATE%2CRUNNER_STATE%2CRUNNER_EXCHANGE_PRICES_BEST&marketIds=".$marketIds,
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
        CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
        CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
        CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30000,
        CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
        CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "GET",
        CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false
    ));

        $response2 = curl_exec($curl2);
        $err2 = curl_error($curl2);
        curl_close($curl2);

    if ($err2){
        echo "cURL Error #:" . $err2;
    }else{
        $odds_array = json_decode($response2,true);
        foreach ($odds_array['eventTypes'][0]['eventNodes'] as $key2 => $value2){
            foreach ($value2['marketNodes'][0]['runners'] as $key_runner => $value_runner){
                $price_data[$value_runner['selectionId']] = @$value_runner['exchange']['availableToBack'][0]['price'];
                $size_data[$value_runner['selectionId']] = @$value_runner['exchange']['availableToBack'][0]['size'];
            };
        }
        //die;
    }

    foreach ($master_data as $key => $value){
        $back_odds = @$price_data[$value['selectionId']];
        echo $value['image'];
        echo $value['runnerName']."<br>";
        echo "<strong>Jockey: </strong>". $value['jockey']."<br>";
        echo "<strong>Venue: </strong>".$value['venue']."<br>";
        echo "<strong>Date/Time: </strong>".$value['dateTime']."<br>";
        echo "<strong>Betfair Back Odds: </strong>".$back_odds."<br>";
        echo "<hr>";
    }
}
}
echo "<br>";
?>
```

Please leave me know if it fix your code.